# What does this SQL do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does this SQL do?

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @S =  ISNULL( @S + ',' ,' ') + c.name
FROM  sys.all_columns c
JOIN  sys.tables      t  ON  c.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE t.name = '$DestinationTable$'

SELECT 'SELECT ' + @S + ' FROM $SourceTable$'
```

This sql is written by someone in my Organization but right now no-one knows how it works.

This code copies data from one table to the other. Source and Destination tables are in different databases.

My question is , does it copy the data matching the column names or does it directly just copy it over?

Comment: This code **copies** nothing, all it does is construct a `SELECT` statement. PS: code formatting matters, so I made it more readable; please do that yourself the next you post a question.

Comment: Using the $xxx$ format hints that this is oracle not sql-server.  Are you sure you have the right tags?

Comment: It creates a select query that reads all columns from a given table, no data is copied in that code snippet.

Comment: Note that the behavior of aggregate string concatenation (concatenating a variable with multi-row results) is undefined in SQL Server. One should use a `XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG` to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to print the `@S` variable and see what it does?

I tested it with the following tables for illustration:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source](
    [BudgetID] [int] NULL,
    [RecordID] [int] NULL,
    [BDate] [date] NULL,
    [Percentage] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destination](
    [BudgetID] [int] NULL,
    [RecordID] [int] NULL,
    [BDate] [date] NULL,
    [Percentage] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

And replaced the variables/parameters with those table names:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)  

SELECT @S =  ISNULL( @S + ',' ,' ') +   c.name   
FROM  sys.all_columns c  join sys.tables  t  ON  c.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE t.name = 'Destination'

SELECT 'SELECT ' + @S + ' FROM  Source'
```

Result:

```
SELECT BudgetID,RecordID,BDate,Percentage,Status FROM  Source
```

As you can see, it gets all columns from the destination table in order to build a select string with all those columns from the source table. (Probably to not cause any issues in case the destination table is missing some of the columns that the source table has).

Comment: `@s` should probably be initialized to NULL, the leading comma is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It takes all table's columns from system table and creates a SELECT query with mentioned column names.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
```

Writing query this way is a bad practice.

According to rules you need to specify columns. and that query returns correct Select statement for a given table name.

Answer (score 0):

This statement uses the schema repository to dynamically create a column list of a table named "$DestinationTable$", which seems to be a variable replaced by a real table name by the runtime environment (the tool that is used to run the script), and then returns a string that can be pasted into a query window and run to select all columns from that table.

It is a handy tool to get a SELECT <every column> FROM <table> script.
The script itself does not copy or insert anything.

Answer (score 0):

In this query, the variable `@s` will contain all the column names of `$DestinationTable$`
Just try printing the variable `@s` to know what all columns it contain. it is better to explicitly write the column names as this query imparts additional expense of finding the table names.